# How to reduce calculation time for iterative functions that involve squaring a number in every iteration. Working with numbers in millions of digits

Tags: abstract-algebra, optimization, computational-complexity, square-numbers

**Introduction**

I have the below function that is iterated a fixed number of times n. The result of the previous is used in the next iteration and so on. Until we have done n iterations

f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> - 2

We always start with x = 4. This means our first iteration looks as below

4<sup>2</sup> - 2 = 14

x = 14 will be used in the next iteration and so on until n iterations are done. Then we stop.

**Problem**

The number of iterations that are to be done is in millions(up to 9 digits). If you see, squaring numbers these many times is not feasible at all even by a computer. The reason is the number of digits in the number resulting from each iteration goes up to more than a million digits in just a few hundred iterations. And we know the larger the number the more time and space it takes. Surely, this needs to be optimized.

**Partly solution**

I tried breaking down the above function to allow better calculation times. Below is what I did.

I broke the function into two parts

1. The x<sup>2</sup> part
2. The -2 part

If we are squaring a number for n number of times, we can make it easier by doing the below.

x<sup>(2<sup>n</sup>)</sup> - Where n is the number of iterations to be done. So, we raise x to the power of 2<sup>n</sup>

e.g: n = 3, x = 4

Iterative

1. 4<sup>2</sup>   = 16
2. 16<sup>2</sup>  = 256
3. 256<sup>2</sup> = 65536

This can also be done without iteration with x<sup>(2<sup>n</sup>)</sup> as:

4<sup>(2<sup>3</sup>)</sup> = 4<sup>(8)</sup> =  65536 | Same result without any iteration

Since we are always starting with 4, we can always use the below

4<sup>(2<sup>n</sup>)</sup>

This will improve the calculation time drastically because I will always be using the number as a power of 4 for other calculations.

**Missing part**

If you see the original function, it has the -2 part and the result is used in the next iteration and so on up to n iterations

f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> **- 2**

This has not been applied to 4<sup>(2<sup>n</sup>)</sup>

For us to make the new solution same as the original equation, we need to subtract something.

such that, 4<sup>(2<sup>n</sup>)</sup> - y.

Where y is the something we need to subtract.

The issue now is, **how can we find the 'y' in this scenario?**

Using iterations here to find y is okay but it is preferred to not use if the number can get very large(more than hundreds of digits). I have not calculated how large this number can get.

It'll also be appreciated if you let me know if you find any flaws in my math.

Comment: If you iterate $f$ a million times, the resulting number will have about 10^{10^5} digits, so you won't even be able to store the answer! Are you only interested in knowing *roughly* how big the answer is? Or are you only interested in the last few digits?

Comment: I am interested in the whole final number. Storage not a problem, only the power the no 4 has as per above calc is needed to store. The f will further be optimized this way. After every 100-1000s iterations, (determinable by other variables not necessary here) the resulting no will be checked against a no in the form 2^p. Since 4 = 2^2, we will just need to check powers. if check we are doing is positive, then the last result x from function f will be optimized and hence x will be drastically reduced. the new x will be iterated further. Until n iterations are done with same checks in between

Comment: @WilliamHoza As above comment for me to optimize the x resulting from f after certain iterations < n, the y still needs to be calculated

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you start with $x_0=4$ and continue with $x_{n+1}=x^2_n-2$, it's easy to prove (by induction) that $$x_n=(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^n}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{2^n}\tag1.$$ That shows that the difference $y_n=4^{2^n}-x_n$ is asymptotically even much bigger than $x_n$. Since all positive powers of $2-\sqrt{3}$ are $<1$, an immediate consequence of (1) is $$x_n=\left\lceil(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^n}\right\rceil\tag2.$$
Now, it depends what you are intending to achieve with the whole thing: If you need just the most significant figures, (2) will be enough. If you need the last few digits, or more generally $x_n\pmod{p^k}$ with some prime $p$, you'll use (1). That's especially  easy if $3$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$. It's possible also if it isn't, but a bit more complicated.
EDIT: The derivation is simple, if we assume that the starting value $x_0>=2$. Then, we can assume $x_n=u_n+\dfrac1{u_n}$ with $u_n\ge1$, and we obtain
$$u_{n+1}+\frac1{u_{n+1}}=\left(u_n+\dfrac1{u_n}\right)^2-2=u^2_n+\dfrac1{u^2_n},$$  implying $$u_{n+1}=u^2_n.$$ The starting value is $$u_0=\frac{x_0+\sqrt{x^2_0-4}}2.$$

Comment: FWIW, starting with $x_0 = 4$, the least significant digit of $f(x)$ should always be 4, I think.

Comment: @professor-vector Thank you for the answer. It was really helpful. However, I have another question. what can be done if we want to start x0 as some arbitrary number say r. Then what will the formula look like. It will be preferred if you could mention how you derived it.

Comment: @Ankit I've made an edit, adding the details you requested.